# splitting/grouping pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, split, grouping

I have a dataframe with a column populated with groups of 1s and 0s. How can I assign each group a consecutive number beginning from 1?

I have tried a for loop across rows, but I need a column operation for fast performance.

```
d = {'col1': [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1
```

`col1
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   0
5   1
6   1
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  1
11  1`

I need the following output:

`col1  col2
0   1   1
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   0   2
4   0   2
5   1   3
6   1   3
7   0   4
8   0   4
9   0   4
10  1   5
11  1   5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare shifted values for not equal and add cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df1['col2'] = df1['col1'].ne(df1['col1'].shift()).cumsum()
print (df1)
    col1  col2
0      1     1
1      1     1
2      1     1
3      0     2
4      0     2
5      1     3
6      1     3
7      0     4
8      0     4
9      0     4
10     1     5
11     1     5
```